# Magento2: Invalid configuration file: config.php

Tags: magento2

I see issue during update cron:

```
Ran jobs by schedule.
Invalid configuration file: '/home/domains/domain.com/public_html/app/etc/config.php'
Ran jobs by schedule.
```

In this file I see module status. Anyone have any solution how to solve?

Comment: Can you update your config.php file to your question?